# Formulário de edição de registro não altera

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, sql-update

Em uma página eu tenho um formulário de cadastro de materiais, em outra eu tenho uma tabela que mostra todos os materiais cadastrados com um botão pra alterar as informações sobre um material e esse botão abre uma terceira página com o mesmo formulário da primeira página só que já preenchido com as informações só pra você alterar.

Só que quando eu altero as informações e clico pra salvar, aparece o script de salvo e ele não altera as informações.

Esse é o meu formulário de edição:

```
<?php
    require 'strcon.php';
    $query = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT MATERIAL FROM materiais");
    $material = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MATERIAL');
    $quantidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'QUANTIDADE');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
?>

    <!-- formulário -->
    <form method="POST" action="update-est.php">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="MATERIAL">Material:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MATERIAL" name="MATERIAL" value="<?php echo $material; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="QUANTIDADE">Quantidade:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="QUANTIDADE" name="QUANTIDADE" value="<?php echo $quantidade;?>">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <hr>
```

E esse é o meu update:

```
<!--Update Estoque-->
<?php

    $quantidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'QUANTIDADE');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sis_tam') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "UPDATE  `sis_tam`.`materiais` SET  `QUANTIDADE` =  '$quantidade' WHERE  `materiais`.`ID` = '$id' ";
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';


?>
```

Alguém consegue identificar o porque de isso estar acontecendo?

Comment: Comenta todo  "echo script" aquele e tenta imprimir o teu $sql em tela e testa ele na mão.

Comment: string(84) "UPDATE `sis_tam`.`materiais` SET `QUANTIDADE` = '3' WHERE `materiais`.`ID` = '' " `Parece que ele não tá pegando o ID

Comment: tenta imprimir esse $id la de cima, se não der nada da uma olhada na pagina anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não esta enviando seu id no formulário, ele precisa constar em um 
`<input type="hidden" .../>`

e também dê uma estudada em design patterns, qualidade do codigo essas coisas... Porque eu não sei em que nível você está, mas a qualidade desse código está bem precária: banco acoplado, multi responsabilidade, acesso a dados na view...

Comment: Amigo, meu nível é "me inscrevi pra uma vaga de django e me enfiaram em uma de php".

Comment: Puts :/ é..essas armadilhas de trampo são fodas
bom se quiser dar uma olhada depois: http://pokephp.com.br/
e tbm o slack do PHPSP, será muito bem vinda :) https://phpsp-slackin.jelasticlw.com.br/